# jqPlot doesn't show all expected bars

Tags: javascript, html, jqplot

my jqPlot doesn't show all expected bars. Can anyone please say what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
plot5 = $.jqplot('chart1', [[
                             [1,1], 
                             [3,2], 
                             [2,6], 
                             [5,4],
                             [7,6],
                             [5,6]
                           ]], {
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal',
            highlightMouseDown: true   
        },
        pointLabels: {show: true, formatString: '%d'}
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        }
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSjqv.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jqPlot is showing all the bars, but you have multiple points with the same y-axis value so they are overlapping.  If you order your points by y values, it would look like this:

```
[1,1]
[3,2] 
[5,4] 
[2,6] //
[5,6] // All have same y value of 6
[7,6] //
```

Notice the last three items all have the same y value. This would results in  multiple overlapping bars on that point. If you look at the image you provided, you can see the first bar has 3 layers of horizontal bars at `x=2`, `x=5` and `x=7`.

Comment: You're welcome. Also please accept the answer if it resolves the question. Thanks